# Instantiate class dynamically based on some constant in Java

Tags: java, reflection, instantiation

I am making a multiplayer game which makes heavy use of a serialisable `Event` class to send messages over a network. I want to be able to reconstruct the appropriate subclass of `Event` based on a constant.

So far I have opted for the following solution:

```
public class EventFactory {

    public static Event getEvent(int eventId, ByteBuffer buf) {
        switch (eventId){
        case Event.ID_A:
            return EventA.deserialise(buf);
        case Event.ID_B:
            return EventB.deserialise(buf);
        case Event.ID_C:
            return EventC.deserialise(buf);
        default:
            // Unknown Event ID
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

However, this strikes me as being very verbose and involves adding a new 'case' statement every time I create a new `Event` type.

I am aware of 2 other ways of accomplishing this, but neither seems better*:

1. Create a mapping of constants -> Event subclasses, and use clazz.newInstance() to instantiate them (using an empty constructor), followed by clazz.initialiase(buf) to supply the necessary parameters.
2. Create a mapping of constants -> Event subclasses, and use reflection to find and call the right method in the appropriate class.

Is there a better approach than the one I am using? Am I perhaps unwise to disregard the alternatives mentioned above?

---

*NOTE: in this case better means simpler / cleaner but without compromising too much on speed.

Comment: How many kinds of events are there? Is there a particular reason to not use some standard wire format, such as JSON or XML?

Comment: Why not have Event implement [Serializable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), then write and read the Event objects directly?

Comment: At the moment there are ~20 Event types, but I will continue to add more. Currently I am serialising / deserialising the Events manually using ByteBuffers as you can see here, because it is fast and very minimal; I want to send as few bytes as possible. I can't use Serializable because I am sending the data in packets rather than streams. I am curious about JSON though - how would that compare with regards to speed and the amount of data being sent?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a `HashMap<Integer,Event>` to get the correct Event for the eventID. Adding or removing events is going to be easy, and as the code grows this is easy to maintain when compared to switch case solution and speed wise also this should be faster than switch case solution.

```
   static
   {
         HashMap<Integer,Event> eventHandlerMap = new HashMap<>();

         eventHandlerMap.put(eventId_A, new EventHandlerA());
         eventHandlerMap.put(eventId_B, new EventHandlerB());
         ............
   }
```

Instead of your switch statement Now you can just use :

```
   Event event = eventHandlerMap.get(eventId);
   if(event!=null){
      event.deserialise(buf);
   }
```

Comment: I like the idea of using a map, but this relies on creating an instance of each Event (I'm using 'EventHandler' is supposed to be 'Event') in advance, seemingly just as placeholders, and relies on empty constructors, making it similar to the first alternative I suggested.

Comment: You can use a eventid to class name mapping and then create the class by reflection. But reflection is generally considered to be slow. By the way I was trying to press the idea of using a hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not afraid of reflection, you could use:

```
    private static final Map<Integer, Method> EVENTID_METHOD_MAP = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    static {
        try {
            for (Field field : Event.class.getFields())
                if (field.getName().startsWith("ID_")) {
                    String classSuffix = field.getName().substring(3);
                    Class<?> cls = Class.forName("Event" + classSuffix);
                    Method method = cls.getMethod("deserialize", ByteBuffer.class);
                    EVENTID_METHOD_MAP.put(field.getInt(null), method);
                }
        } catch (IllegalAccessException|ClassNotFoundException|NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
        }
    }

    public static Event getEvent(int eventId, ByteBuffer buf)
    throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        return (Event) EVENTID_METHOD_MAP.get(eventId).invoke(null, buf);
    }
```

This solution requires that `int ID_N` always maps to `class EventN`, where `N` can be any String where all characters return `true` for the method `java.lang.Character.isJavaIdentifierPart(c)`.  Also, `class EventN` must define a static method called `deserialize` with one `ByteBuffer` argument that returns an `Event`.

You could also check if `field` is static before trying to get its field value.  I just forget how to do that at the moment.

Comment: I'm open to this. It doesn't look too scary, but I don't know if the advantages outweigh the complications. How would this compare speed-wise to the switch statement?